# How to insert HTML attribute into an element which is on page loaded in Android WebView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to insert an attribute into an `<i>` element on a page, which is loaded in Android WebView.

**How should it work?**

For example, I have m.facebook.com loaded in my WebView. Now I want to add an attribute src="mydata" to every `<i>` tag. So, in result I will have the same page, but each `<i>` element now will contain src="mydata" (`<i src="mydata"></i>`).

How can I do it? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The example of JavaScript code you want is below:

```
var i_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('i');
for (var i = 0; i < i_tag.length; i++) {
    i_tag[i].setAttribute('src', 'mydata');
}
```

So what you need to do is to call JavaScript function when the webpage loaded via `loadUrl()`

```
final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                "var i_tag = document.getElementsByTagName('i');" +
                "for (var i = 0; i < i_tag.length; i++) {i_tag[i].setAttribute('src', 'mydata');}" +
                "})();");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

    }
});

webView.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com/");
```

Comment: If this is the right answer try to [mark an answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so others can see it :)

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work for me. What I'm trying to do is to add an onclick="ok.performClick(this.style)" attribute to the each i element on a page. But it doesn't work for me. It looks like I'm doing it totally wrong. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/sfilmak/3260bd91f7ac240bba407a783b17a522 Thank you!

Comment: So the result you want is like this? `<i onclick="ok.performClick(this.style)">Some italic text</i>`

Comment: I wonder why your for loop not using `.length` and I found that `"https://m.facebook.com/"` just contain six `<i>` tag